# Comparing a Number Object of unknown integral type

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to compare two `Object` whose type is unknown during runtime, but it is at least guaranteed that the type will be some form of `Number`. Is there a way to compare an `Object` whose base class is `Number` without explicitly casting the object to one of Java's integral types?

So, for example:

```java
Object objectInt1 = (Integer) 5;
Object objectInt2 = (Integer) 6;

if (objectInt1 > objectInt2) {
    // Clearly won't compile
}

if ((Number) objectInt1 > (Number) objectInt2) {
    // This of course won't compile either
}
```

The only way I can think to accomplish this is by using `instanceof` and check for each integral type, and do explicit casting. But maybe there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: How about defining a method with generics of type number?

Answer (score 2):

If you know they will be Number, you can use:

```
Object object1 = Integer.valueOf(5);
Object object2 = Float.valueOf(6);

Number number1 = (Number) object1;
Number number2 = (Number) object2;

if (number1.doubleValue() < number2.doubleValue()) {
  System.out.println("number1 < number2");
}
```

Of course you can also do your casting inline.

Comment: I don't suppose you lose anything by treating everything as a double. Does this play well with `Long`?

Comment: My understanding was that they could be any numbers, including Float and Double. With Longs you might end up losing precision. I suupose it's a question of what to lose. Compaing 6.5 with 6 or very large but always integral numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two “integral” types of `Number`: `Integer` and `Long`, and an `Integer` can safely be expressed as a `Long`.

The `Number` type has the [`longValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html#longValue()) method, so you can safely cast to `Number` and compare the result of calling that method:

```
if (((Number)object1).longValue() > ((Number)object2).longValue())
```

Comment: If the type is `Double`, wouldn't I be losing that precision by converting to long?

Comment: @user0000001 actually the opposite is true, you *lose* precision using double. The question specified *integral* types, which means `Integer` or `Long`. Large `Long` values can not be accurately represented as double value, and you lose precision converting them to double. Java uses [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which uses only 53 bits max for the "number" part, so long values larger than 2 ^ 54 are only approximations when converted to a double.

Answer (score 0):

To compare something you must know how to do it. So you cant just take something unknown and compare it to something else.

Operators < > are defined for primitive types only.

Objects that are meant to be compared implement Comparable interface. You can check that Object implements it and call compareTo method to compare Objects of the same type. All common java number types (Integer, Short, BigDecimal) implement Comparable.